# Deployment completes but changes are not reflected in the output

Tags: java, github-actions

I try to deploy a jar file with GitHub Actions. The problem I face is that GitHub Actions workflow shows that deployment is successful but when I try to check the changes, I find that there is no new change in the output.

However when I try to manually deploy the same thing from the server it show the exact changes. Below is the workflow that I use:

```
  deploy:
    needs: [build]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      DEV_AWS_INSTANCE_SG_ID: ${{secrets.DEV_INSTANCE_SG}}
    steps:
      - name: configure aws credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}
          aws-region: ap-south-1
      - name: get runner ip address
        id: ip
        uses: haythem/public-ip@v1.2
      - name: whitelist runner ip address
        run: |
          aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress \
            --group-id $DEV_AWS_INSTANCE_SG_ID \
            --protocol tcp \
            --port 22 \
            --cidr ${{steps.ip.outputs.ipv4}}/32
      - name: ssh-deploy
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{secrets.DEV_HOST}}
          username: ${{secrets.DEV_USERNAME}}
          key: ${{secrets.DEV_KEY}}
          port: ${{secrets.DEV_PORT}}
          script: |
            cd ${{secrets.DEV_APP_FOLDER}}
            cp ${{secrets.DEV_APP_FOLDER}}/example-SNAPSHOT.jar ${{secrets.DEV_BU_FOLDER}}/example-SNAPSHOT_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S).jar
            rm ${{secrets.DEV_APP_FOLDER}}/example-SNAPSHOT.jar
            export DB_HOST=${{secrets.DEV_DB_HOST}}
            export DB_USER=${{secrets.DEV_DB_USER}}
            export DB_PASS='${{secrets.DEV_DB_PASS}}'
            aws s3 cp s3://${{secrets.AWS_BUCKET_NAME}}/example-SNAPSHOT.jar ${{secrets.DEV_APP_FOLDER}}/example-SNAPSHOT.jar
            chmod -R 777 example-SNAPSHOT.jar
            npx kill-port ${{secrets.APP_PORT}}
             
            nohup java -DB_HOST=${{secrets.DEV_DB_HOST}} -DB_USER=${{secrets.DEV_DB_USER}} -DB_PASS='${{secrets.DEV_DB_PASS}}' -DSENDGRID_API_KEY='S${{secrets.SENGRID_API_KEY}}' -DAWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME='${{secrets.DAWS_S3_BUCKET}}' -DAWS_S3_OBJECT_KEY='${{secrets.DAWS_S3_OBJECT_KEY}}' -jar ${{secrets.DEV_APP_FOLDER}}/example-SNAPSHOT.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &

      - name: revoke runner ip address
        run: |
          aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress \
            --group-id $DEV_AWS_INSTANCE_SG_ID \
            --protocol tcp \
            --port 22 \
            --cidr ${{steps.ip.outputs.ipv4}}/32
```

How can I deploy this jar file to the server which can reflect the output?

Comment: From your workflow, it looks like the `build` job builds and copies the JAR file to AWS S3 bucket; and then, the `deploy` job, after SSHing into your server, copies it and runs it, is that correct? What about logs? Is there any indication that the file is not copied? Did you check and verify the PID?

Comment: @Azeem I have checked but there is nothing in the log. you are correct about the deployment process. the file is copied to the server without any issue from s3. GitHub actions also show that job is successful, however when I try to check the change it doesnot appear.

Comment: How do you check it? Did you check the timestamps of the newly copied (or existing) JAR files with `ls -l`? Run a deployment and observe the process in the server. See if its PID changes e.g. `ps aux | grep java`.

Comment: @Azeem thank you for your reply. first I checked the timestamps of the copied file. and also check the server's public dns along with the app port and the status. (server public IPV4 DNS:port/api/status) which shows me the api status. which is share by my developer to me for checking.

Comment: Right. Are the timestamps new? Is that backup being created by the `cp` command? Also, verify if your `build` job is actually uploading the new JAR file to your S3 bucket.

Comment: @Azeem, sorry for the late reply. I have checked all the file timestapms and it show that jar is copied from s3 and backup is also taken at the right time. the problem is that the change developer made is not showing while deploy through Github Action.

Comment: Well, if the file is being copied and updated properly by the `deploy` job then you need to verify if the `build` job is actually building the newer version. You may simply upload the built JAR file as an artifact and download and test it manually on the server to make sure it's the updated one.